# MVC4 EF DB First - How to access a models foreign key (ICollection)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model, foreign-key-relationship, icollection

I created a MSSQL database with tables containing foreign keys. I then created a new MVC 4 web application. I used Entity Framework to generate my controllers/models/views. In the models, tables that were linked using foreign keys appear as ICollections. For example:

```
 public partial class Test
{

    public Test()
    {
        this.Questions = new HashSet<Question>();
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int testId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> pointValue { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> numberOfQuestions { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My question is how am I able to access the data stored in those ICollections in a view? Test.Questions[x] <-- gives errors.

Comment: For clarification, do you have a model for `Question` and `User`?

Comment: `((Test)test).Questions[0].QuestionType`? it's a collection, so you're going to have to reference a single instance before you can access its properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was more simple than I expected. I just needed to use a foreach loop:

```
    @foreach (var question in item.Questions)
    {
        <td>@question.question1</td>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ICollection<T>` is just like an `IList<T>` or `T[]`, so you're going to have to get an element within the collection first then reference its properties. e.g.

```
Test test = testService.Get(1);
Question question = test.Questions.FirstOrDefault(); // using System.Linq;
if (question.quertionType == ....)
{
}
```